# CSS 3D transform support for Spotify Apps

Tags: css, webkit, spotify

Is there a particular reason why CSS 3D Transforms are not supported in Spotify Apps?

I would really love to use them in an app that I already built for Safari/Chrome, but this is preventing me from doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, unfortunately, that we're using a branch of Chromium that doesn't support it correctly yet.

We do plan to fix this in the future, but for now you're out of luck.

Comment: Looking forward to it! Thanks for the answer.